# What are the exact measurements of this pipe thread?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, threading

I would like to 3D print something that fits into this threading:

[image: pipe]

For that I would need the exact measurements of that thread, but without knowing what the standard is called it's hard to look them up.

Edit: As requested in the comments, I have measured the pitch, it is about 2.3 mm.

Comment: Is it metric or NPS (national pipe thread) ? It could be 2" NPS. "Taper" is another critical dimension. I believe NPS is in ASTM A450 also in ANSI but I don'e know the section. An EU document would be needed for metric.

Comment: There is a British standard I think it is “BPS” I found this last week looking up a fitting for another user.

Comment: It's in Thailand, which is officially metric but uses a lot of US standards. But is plumbing *ever* metric? Even in Germany we use names like `3/8"` for taps and the like. (Although I think there is no actual diameter of 3/8 inch on such a tap.)

Comment: My guess is it's NPT, 4.9cm is pretty close to 1.9", which is the outside diameter of 1.5" rigid pipe. You might start with National Pipe Thread on Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_pipe_thread